# WPF open source control to replace infragistics xamdatagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

We have an old version of WPF infragistics controls and we would like to consider replacing it with an open source library, it must have an open license so we can distribute it.

I would like to start with an data grid control. like xamDatGrid

https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/xamdatagrid

automatic sorting can be switched on and off.
automatic column definitions and editing columns to a specific style
fast UI rendering.

enabling user to select which columns to display and which not.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout [WPF DataGrid](https://www.syncfusion.com/wpf-ui-controls) by Syncfusion if you are eligible for [free community license](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: I work for Intel I can't use license like that.

Comment: Is it [tag:gratis] or [tag:open-source]? OP was asking for open source.